# HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed in cURL

Tags: php

Here is my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) and ($_REQUEST['email']) and ($_REQUEST['msg'])){
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email= $_REQUEST['email'];
    $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    $url="http://14.140.111.4:20002/ContactUs?name=$name&Email=$email&Message=$msg";
    $url = urlencode($url);
    $curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here urlencode
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Cubewires Sample cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'Email' => $email,
            'Message'=>$msg
        )
    ));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($resp);
// Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);
}

?>
```

i  got response HTTP Error 400. while using this API data should be inserted in database.
Thanks,
vivek

Comment: Pass your variables in the post fields only. Don't pass them into the URL.

Comment: @aynber nothing happen when i remove variable from URL.

Comment: use http_build_query instead of simply inserting your stuff in url.